# Formal integration (?) in Chabauty’s method

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, lie-groups, arithmetic-geometry

In Mccallum, Poonen’s paper “The method of Chabauty and Coleman”,
the authors define, for the Jacobian $J$ of a geometrically connected smooth proper curve over the rational field and for $\omega \in H^0(J_{\mathbb{Q}_p}, \Omega)$, the “integration” $J(\mathbb{Q}_p) \to \mathbb{Q}_p$, which is a homomorphism and is calculated by formally integrating the $\omega$ as a formal power series on an open subgroup of $J(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, and evaluating the rational point.

It seems that it is defined as follows:
first define it on an open subgroup as the formal integration discribed above, and then next extend it on the whole of $J(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

But I can’t understand it.

The authors say that we need a theory of Lie groups.
But its reference (Bourbaki) only treats the usual Lie group, but not $p$-adic Lie groups.
And I don’t know even the theory of usual Lie groups.

So would you explain the definition of this integratin only using the theory of algebraic geometry?

I know some fundamental theory of algebraic geometry such as Neron models and formal groups, which is mentioned in this paper.

**EDIT**

I understood that for a complete DVR $R$ with the fraction $K$ and the residue field $k$, an abelian variety $A$ over $K$, its Neron model $A$ over $R$, and for its formal group $F$ over $R$, we have $F(\mathfrak{m}) \cong \operatorname{ker}(A(K) \to A(k))$.

So it suffices to define the formal logarithm for a formal group and its invariant differential.

In Silverman's AEC and Hazewinkel's Formal groups and applications, they treat only formal logarithm of formal groups of one variable.

How can I define it for higher dimensional formal groups?

Comment: Bourbaki treats in a uniform way Lie groups over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or  a non-discrete complete ultrametric ﬁeld. With a special section (III, §8) for the case of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: IMHO one should learn "usual Lie groups" before Néron models, but never mind that. If you know formal groups it should be ok. Express the differential in the local coordinates of your formal group. Then integrate that power series formally. The resulting powerseries converges on a layer of the formal group $\hat J(p^k\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and that is a finite index subgroup of $J(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thank you very much! I understand a part, but still don't understand one point. I edited the question, so I would be greteful if you check it.

Comment: For the formal logarithm of a higher-dimensional group, you can pick a basis of the space of invariant $1$-forms, integrate each basis vector in formal power series, and define this tuple of integrals to be the formal logarithm. Using the basis you can identify this with a vector in the tangent space at the identity.

Comment: @WillSawin $\Omega_0 = \oplus \mathscr{O} dx_i$, where $x_i$ are a parameter of $A$ at $0$. So $H^0(\Omega) \subseteq \oplus K[[X]] dx_i$. So the expansion of an invariant 1 form is in $K[[X]]^g$. So what is the integratin? Is it an element of $K[[X]]^g$? If so, what is the evaluation of the point of $F(\mathfrak{m})$? It should be an element of $K$, but now it is in $K^g$.

Comment: The invariant one-form is necessarily exact. Concretely, this means if we write it as $\sum_i f_i dx_i$, that $ \frac{\partial f_i} {\partial x_j} = \frac{ \partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$. Because the ring $K[[X]]$ has no higher de Rham cohomology, every exact one-form is the derivative of a function. Take the unique one with zero constant term. That is, there exists a power series $g$ with $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} =f_i$ for all $i$ and $g(0,\dots,0)=0$. You can find it by picking the coefficients of the monomials one at a time.

Comment: @WillSawin Thank you very much! This is exactly what I want. I’m not familiar with de Rham theory for algebraic geometry, but I’ll try it.

Comment: In this case it's just the algebra of formal power series. You just want to check that for every nonconstant monomial appearing in $g$, there is a unique coefficient that works.

Comment: Coleman's "Effective Chabauty" used his theory of integration to construct the Log. Serre's "Lectures on the M-W theorem" mentions that one can use Bourbaki's "Lie Groups" III 7.6. In a recent work with a co-author, it was more convenient for us to use Bourbaki's approach, but we had to be careful about convergence in explicit disks. See Sec 7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.01055